# Windows Azure and Xampp

Tags: azure

I have installed Xampp on my Windows Server 2012 instance on Windows Azure. I can't get port forwarding to work. I can access my webpage via the internal IP address on the server fine, just not from outside.

Here are my endpoints: 
[image]

Comment: enable port 80 using following Link [Enable Port](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934283.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. 
Disabled `Enable Direct Server Return`

Xampp works perfectly now.